# perform element operation depending on condition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have raw data and want to calibrate it depending on the value.
I would like to do something like this but in a numpy way.

```
arr = list(range(1000)) # random array
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] > 200 and arr[i] < 500:
        arr[i] = arr[i]*2.5
    elif arr[i] >= 500 and arr[i] < 1000:
        arr[i] = arr[i]*2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change much if you want a working code:

```
arr = np.arange(1000) # similar to range(1000)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]): # use arr.shape[0]
    if 200 < arr[i] < 500:  # can simplify here
        arr[i] = arr[i]*2.5
    elif 500 <= arr[i] < 1000:
        arr[i] = arr[i]*2.3
```

Also you could do complex logical operations something like

```
arr[np.logical_and(arr > 200, arr < 500)] *= 2.5
arr[np.logical_and(arr > 500, arr < 1000)] *= 2.3
```

which will make operation with only elements of array that follow the written condition in square brackets

Comment: This will require multiple passes of `arr`, one for each condition.

Comment: Sure, but it will probably still be faster than python for-loop